# Hacer que elementos hijos salgan del padre con css

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Tengo este carousel con css y query:

**html:**

```
<div class="productos-recomendados">
  <h2 class="text-center">PRODUCTOS</h2>
  <p class="text-center">Este es nuestro catalogo de productos</p>
  <div class="contenedor-principal">
    <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>
    <div class="contenedor-carousel">
     <div class="carousel">
      <div class="panel panel-default producto">
       <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
       <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="img/sal1.jpg">
        <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
        <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
       </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="panel panel-default producto">
       <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
       <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="img/sal2.jpg">
        <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
        <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default producto">
       <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
       <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="img/sal3.jpg">
        <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
        <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default producto">
       <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
       <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="img/sal4.jpg">
        <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
        <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal,
.categorias .contenedor-principal {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda,
.productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha,
.categorias .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda,
.categorias .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 40%;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 500;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .2s ease all;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda,
.categorias .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda {
    left: 0;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha,
.categorias .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha {
    right: 0;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel,
.categorias .contenedor-carousel {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel,
.categorias .contenedor-carousel .carousel {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel .producto,
.categorias .contenedor-carousel .carousel .categoria {
    min-width: 280px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel .producto.hover,
.categorias .contenedor-carousel .carousel .categoria.hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
    var fila;
    var productos;
    
    var flechaIzquierda;
    var flechaDerecha;
    
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        fila = $('.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel');
        productos = $('.producto');
        
        flechaIzquierda = $('#flecha-izquierda');
        flechaDerecha = $('#flecha-derecha');
        
        /* Eventos para las flechas */
        
        $(flechaDerecha).on("mouseover", function(){
            $(this).css("opacity", 0.3);
        });
        
        $(flechaDerecha).on("mouseout", function(){
            $(this).css("opacity", 0);
        });
        
        $(flechaIzquierda).on("mouseover", function(){
            $(this).css("opacity", 0.3);
        });
        
        $(flechaIzquierda).on("mouseout", function(){
            $(this).css("opacity", 0);
        });
        
        $(flechaDerecha).on("click", function(){
            if(fila.scrollLeft() <= fila.width())
            {
                var scrollDer = fila.scrollLeft() + fila.width(); 
                fila.scrollLeft(scrollDer);
            }
            else
                fila.scrollLeft(0);
        });
        
        $(flechaIzquierda).on("click", function(){
            if(fila.scrollLeft() >= fila.width())
            {
                var scrollIzq = fila.scrollLeft() - fila.width(); 
                fila.scrollLeft(scrollIzq);
            }
            else
                fila.scrollLeft(fila.width());
        });
    
    /* Hover */
    
    $(productos).each(function(index, producto){
        $(producto).on("mouseenter", function(e){
            var elemento = e.currentTarget;
            
            setTimeout(function(){
                productos.each(function(index, producto){
                    $(producto).removeClass("hover");
                });
                $(elemento).addClass("hover");
            }, 300);
        });
    });
    
    $(fila).on("mouseleave", function(){
        productos.each(function(index, producto){
            $(producto).removeClass("hover");
        });
    });
});
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es cuando pasa el mouse sobre un elemento hijo (`div` que contiene la clase `producto`) aplico la clase `.hover` esto para hacer una escala a ese elemento hijo y que se haga mas grande a los demás, el problema es que cuando hago la escala el elemento hijo se corta, como puedo solucionar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Eso te ocurre, porque la manera de funcionar de un `carousel` es tener la diapositivas que no están a la vista, saliéndose de su contenedor y ocultándose con un `overflow: hidden` para que de esta manera luego poder ir animando las diapositivas de tal manera que las que se salían parezca que aparecen de uno de los lados de la pantalla. Esto ocasiona que al agrandar tus elementos `.producto` lo que se sale de su contenedor queda cortado.

Para solucionarlo le puedes cambiar la propiedad `overflow: hidden` a tu elemento padre por la propiedad `overflow-x: hidden` para evitar que al agrandarse se corte por arriba y por abajo.

```
.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel,
.categorias .contenedor-carousel {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

En mi ejemplo añadí el efecto de agrandarse con **CSS** cuando se hace un *hover* por encima de un elemento `.producto`, simulando lo que hace tu clase `.hover`.

```css
.productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal,
.categorias .contenedor-principal {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda,
.productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha,
.categorias .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda,
.categorias .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 40%;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 500;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .2s ease all;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda,
.categorias .contenedor-principal .flecha-izquierda {
    left: 0;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha,
.categorias .contenedor-principal .flecha-derecha {
    right: 0;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel,
.categorias .contenedor-carousel {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel,
.categorias .contenedor-carousel .carousel {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel .producto,
.categorias .contenedor-carousel .carousel .categoria {
    min-width: 280px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel .carousel .producto.hover,
.categorias .contenedor-carousel .carousel .categoria.hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transform-origin: center;
}

.producto:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background-color: #fff;
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="productos-recomendados">
  <h2 class="text-center">PRODUCTOS</h2>
  <p class="text-center">Este es nuestro catalogo de productos</p>
  <div class="contenedor-principal">
    <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>
    <div class="contenedor-carousel">
     <div class="carousel">
      <div class="panel panel-default producto">
       <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
       <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="img/sal1.jpg">
        <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
        <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
       </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="panel panel-default producto">
       <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
       <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="img/sal2.jpg">
        <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
        <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default producto">
       <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
       <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="img/sal3.jpg">
        <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
        <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default producto">
       <a href="" class="a-carrito"><span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></a>
       <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="img/sal4.jpg">
        <p class="p-precio">$200.00</p>
        <p class="p-producto">PackEcoSal</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <button role="button" id="flecha-derecha" class="flecha-derecha"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Se sigue cortando el elemento hijo, no tiene nada que ver el tamaño del hijo??

Comment: ¿Qué elemento hijo dices que es el que se corta?

Comment: el elemento hijo que es el div que contiene la clase .producto, a ese div le doy los siguientes tamaños: width: 280px; height: 331px;

Comment: ¿Se corta por arriba y por abajo dices? ¿O por dónde? ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta añadiendo una captura con ese efecto de corte que te sucede?

Comment: Si, se  corta por arriba y por los lados, ya puse capturas

Comment: Entiendo a lo que te refieres. Para poder evitar que se corte tienes que hacer que `.contenedor-carousel` tenga el suficiente espacio para que acoger el crecimiento del elemento `.producto` ya que la propiedad `transform: scale()` provoca un crecimiento "absoluto" que evita que el resto de elementos del DOM se acomoden a su nuevo tamaño. Para hacerlo puedes darle más `padding` a dicho elemento para hacerlo crecer: `.productos-recomendados .contenedor-carousel,
.categorias .contenedor-carousel {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}`